# How do I get to Beedle's island at night?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I can't fly at night, but at Beedle's Island, he says that he does business there at night. I don't see any beds on the island as well. How can I get there?

Comment: Beedle doesn't actually do business at his island at night.  The main reason to go there are to get insects that are only out at night and to get a specific Goddess chest that can't be reached when his ship isn't docked.  Oh, and to get a late-game sidequest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a bed on Beedle's shop that you can sleep on.  Once you sleep there until night, Beedle will park on the island and you can then do business with him (and also find a Gratitude Crystal there as well.)  Sleep in the bed again so you can return.

Comment: While you're at it, talk to Beedle and try to leave his shop without buying anything.

Comment: @Powerlord: That is, when he has things to sell you.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that if you have plenty of health and are ballsy enough, you can get to that chest by skydiving if you time it right. You will likely lose a lot of hearts when you land though.