# Flying at night

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Ok, if you can't fly around at night why is there a little island that says something like `Come back and see me during the night-Beedle?`  There has got to be a way! Maybe we need to obtain those goggles the other birds have?

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42015/6146

Answer (score 11):

The only places you can go at night are those that are connected to beds.

It's important to know that Beedle has a bed in the front of his shop.

> You can sleep in this bed, and end up at the place Beedle stays at night.

Comment: You need to do this to grab some gratitude crystals and fill in the last piece of your inventory.

Comment: You also need to do this to do Beetle's side quest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into beedles air-ship and sleep on his bed, until night then when you wake up you are on his island at night 
:-)